# Android looking for resource in portrait folder even when the app is locked in Landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a weird issue. My application is locked on the landscape. My application is tablet only application supporting 7 inch onwards. So I have created two folders under res folder - layout-sw600dp-land & layout-sw720dp-land and I put all my layout resources under it. It looks fine when screen is rotated, works as expected. But when I rotate my screen and press home button, android looks in portrait folder for resources and app crashes as there is no resource in the portrait folder. Why android looks into portrait folder, even when I mentioned in manifest that application orientation is landscape. Please see my code below. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
   android:name="com.example.activities.fragmentActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
</activity>
```

My Folder structure is as below :

```
res
layout
layout-sw600dp-land
layout-sw720dp-land
```

When I put my resources in layout folder, It will prevent crash. So it is clear that android is looking for resource portrait folder. Could anyone help me to solve this issue.

> StackTrace

```
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041): Process: com.sample.android, PID: 16041
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030003
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at com.sample.android.fragments.sampleFragment.onCreateView(sampleFragment.java:189)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-24 16:40:00.383: E/AndroidRuntime(16041):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it is not that adding resources to layout folder means activity is using portrait mode. It may be the case of device on which you installed does not take resources from layout-sw600dp-land and
layout-sw720dp-land, so it might look for resources in default layout folder.

Comment: I got this issue in nexus 10 and Samsung tab 3 (7 inch). So i dont think , it is not related device.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe putting layouts (or any other resource) in an override directory without a corresponding default layout is supported. Certainly, lint complains if you put a string in a `values-ll` directory and there is no corresponding string in `values`.

My advice would be to move the contents of `layout-sw600dp-land` to `layout`.

You're restricting supported devices by other means, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `configChanges` attribute.

Comment: Hey man, this never seems to a solution for the question.Please only answer if you are sure about what you are saying.

Comment: @SanalVarghese Have you actually tested this? It _might_ be the cause, because it's possible the flag causes `onConfigurationChanged()` to be called with the portrait orientation.

Comment: If I remove configChanges, then how I can lock activity in landscape mode??

Comment: @SanalVarghese The `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"` attribute should be enough for that, I believe. If not, then use  `setRequestedOrientation()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **android:screenOrientation="landscape"**..

Comment: I have tried it....It dosent work...still app crashes....I dont think there is enough difference betwwen landscape and sensor landscape

Comment: can you provide the stack trace of the crash?? It will helpful to diagnose the reason for the crash..

Comment: Hi, I have updated with stack trace. Please check do u have got any clue?

Comment: In R.java check the for the resource file which has this value **#0x7f030003** some error is with that file. I guess it is an xml file.

Comment: It is a constant file created by android for all resources.Actually the resource id here referred is present in  layout-sw600dp-land & layout-sw720dp-land but not found in layout folder. Actually it looks in layout folder. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project try run project or create layout-land folder copy from layout-sw600dp-land

Answer (score 0):

Since you blocked the app in landscape mode it would seem legit for Android to just look in -land layouts.

But it just isn't like that, I wouldn't even call this a bug, the framework just expect to find a default in some occasion. I don't know why that happens.

I would advice to change your folder structure like follow:

```
layout (default = what you used to have in sw600dp-land)
layout-sw720dp (remove -land, not needed since you locked in landscape)
```

if you ever add support for smartphone just move your layout to layout-sw600dp and use the layout folder for your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

try remove the configChanges from your manifest and handle it in your code, so inside the onConfigurationChanged method create an *if* to check if the application is in landscape or portrait.

If your application is lock in landscape so you can do this:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        if (myActivity.isLandscape()) {


        }
   }
```

this will force the android to rebuild your view in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Before few days ago i have face similar issue.

The issue is raised because when ever you rotate device it will go for onConfigurationChange method. Now if you have not manage all your resources in that method then it will surly get crashed.

You can try one thing, Just update your below line,

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

to

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Also remove below line:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

And check it.

If still it get crashed then let me know, i will check with depth in to your issue and will try to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

`screenOrientation` only applies when your activity is in the front. Android expects your activity to be able to exist in the background without crashing, even when the device is in a different orientation. As everyone else has said, don't use unnecessary resource qualifiers.